# Do deleted questions reduce reputation at recalculation time?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-recalc

About ten days ago, my reputation was recalculated. I've lost approximately 180 reputation points at SO. I think this is caused by the upvoted answers to the deleted questions.

Some new users (for example, [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96942/wafaa)) ask same questions again and again, and they delete the questions and then ask them again. Now I'm looking at my answers and I can't see some answers that I got upvotes for. In this case, if I get a reputation calculation, I will lose my reputation from these questions. What do you think about this? Should these scores be removed from me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you'll lose the reputation.

Yes, sometimes that sucks - but at other times it will prevent gaming the system. Ultimately, it means that all your current reputation (at the time of a recalc) is visible and accountable, which I think is worth the slight pain of losing a bit of rep every so often.

Comment: I just lost around 1,500 before reading this ...

Answer (score 2):

If your answer is deleted, either by you or by virtue of being attached to a question that's deleted, then you will lose the reputation gained from that answer at the next recalculation.

If you hit your rep cap on the day that you answered that question then your total might not go down by the full amount as there is previously "unused" reputation available to you.

There is a note somewhere in the FAQ questions about this, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Cheers Jon - My spelling is getting worse and if the red underline doesn't happen I don't always double check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we do lose rep on deleted questions when a recalc is done. For evidence remember the recalc when the association of accounts failed: see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/how-did-i-just-go-down-150-rep-on-so/2112#2112).

Recalcs are done very rarely. I do not see a possibility at the moment to know about deleted questions and answers in a recalc. But the rules for deletion are strict. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228462/how-can-a-question-or-answer-be-deleted).

Remember, reputation is not as important as we seem to make it. We are rewarded, and that is nice, as we usually do not get rewarded very often. And people gaming the system are a nuissance, granted. But life does not depend on a few points of rep. So I can live with this behaviour.